# Loop for rotation of matrix(sql)

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data

I have parent/child matrix

```
Parent_col_ID  Child_col_ID
    1                2
    2                3
    3                4
    3                5
```

I need to modify it to

```
Main_Parent Child1 Child2 Child3
  1            2     3      4
  1            2     3      5
```

How can i do this in sql?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What if you have 10 children for one "main parent", and only 3 children for another? Do you have an upper limit for the number of children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS()` . Here is your query:

```
--DROP TABLE CollEgues
--GO
CREATE TABLE CollEgues
(
     Parent_col_ID  int
     ,Child_col_ID  int
);

INSERT INTO CollEgues VALUES(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(3,5);

SELECT   Main.Parent_col_ID     AS Main_Parent   
        ,Main.Child_col_ID      AS Child1
        ,Child1.Child_col_ID    AS Child2
        ,Child2.Child_col_ID    AS Child3
FROM CollEgues AS Main
    LEFT JOIN  CollEgues AS Child1 ON Main.Child_col_ID = Child1.Parent_col_ID
    LEFT JOIN  CollEgues AS Child2 ON Child1.Child_col_ID = Child2.Parent_col_ID
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CollEgues C WHERE Main.Parent_col_ID=C.Child_col_ID);
```